# Using Heat template parameter value in bash script

Tags: bash, templates, openstack, heat, devstack

In a bash script in a Heat template, is it possible to use a parameter value from that template?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the [Heat Orchestration Template specification](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/heat/template_guide/hot_spec.html#str-replace), you can accomplish this with the `str_replace` function. They give an example that uses `str_replace`, together with `get_param`, to use a parameter value `DBRootPassword` in a bash script:

```
parameters:
  DBRootPassword:
    type: string
    label: Database Password
    description: Root password for MySQL
    hidden: true

resources:
  my_instance:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
      # general properties ...
      user_data:
        str_replace:
          template: |
            #!/bin/bash
            echo "Hello world"
            echo "Setting MySQL root password"
            mysqladmin -u root password $db_rootpassword
            # do more things ...
          params:
            $db_rootpassword: { get_param: DBRootPassword }
```

Each key in `params` is replaced in `template` with its value. Since `$db_rootpassword`'s value is set to the result of `get_param`, that means the parameter is passed into the bash script wherever `$db_rootpassword` is used.